# Angular 2 - Share highlighted text via tooltip

Tags: javascript, angular, tooltip, share

I am new to Angular (brand new, in-fact) and I have been researching how exactly I can go about completing this task but I have not found anything helpful as of yet. I think perhaps I just have no idea what to search for. I am sure this is something that has been done before.

To give you some context: I am busy helping with an Angular 2 project at the moment and what I want to do is when a user highlights some text within an article, a tooltip should popup with different sharing options (Linkedin, Twitter, Email). When the user selects one of these sharing options the text that they highlighted will be pre-populated in the default sharing window of that social media. Basically it is your standard "share this page" functionality, however I want it to be pre-populated with whatever the user highlighted.

I'm afraid I have no code to share because I don't know where to even start. Angular 2 is pretty overwhelming at the moment. I would appreciate any help, even if it is just some reading material or some steps I could follow to help get me going.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out (a week later). Here is what I came up with, for anyone who might like to know. Please also note that I used the plugin Popper.js for the popup.

Here is my HTML (component.html file):

```
<div class="share-highlight" (mouseup)="showSelectedText($event)">
    <p>Some test content here</p>

    <!-- This here is the actual popup and links to social media -->
    <div class="js-popper share-highlight__tooltip" [style.display]="getStyle()">
        <div class="share-highlight__tooltip-arrow"></div>
        <a target="_blank" class="share-highlight__social-icons" href="{{linkedinlink}}"><span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span></a> <a target="_blank" class="share-highlight__social-icons" href="{{twitterlink}}"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a><a class="share-highlight__social-icons" href="{{emaillink}}"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a>
     </div>
</div>
```

And here is what is in my component.ts file which handles the selection and building the share links:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Popper from 'popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js'; // plugin

@Component({
    selector: 'share-highlight',
    templateUrl: './share-highlight.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./share-highlight.component.scss']
})
export class ShareHighlightComponent implements OnInit {

    selectedtext : string = '';
    twitterlink : string = '';
    linkedinlink : string = '';
    emaillink : string = '';

    showStyle : boolean = false;

    showSelectedText(event) {
        let element = event; // this was mostly for testing

        var text = "";
        if (window.getSelection) {
            // Get the text that was selected
            text = window.getSelection().toString();

            if (text != "") {
                // See where the selection is and attach popper to it
                var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

                // Setting up the tooltip (popper)
                let popper = document.querySelector('.js-popper'); 
                new Popper(selection,popper, {
                    placement: 'top'
                });

                // Show popper
                this.showStyle = true;
            } else {
                // Hide popper
                this.showStyle = false;
            }

        } else {
            this.showStyle = false;
        }

        // Value of the selected Text
        this.selectedtext = text;

        // Building the share links with highlighted text and additional info you might want to add
        this.twitterlink = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.WebsiteLinkHere.com&text=" + this.selectedtext.split(' ').join('%20') + "%20via%20@TwitterHandle ";    
        this.linkedinlink = "https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://www.WebsiteLinkHere.com&title=" + ("Title here.").split(' ').join('%20') + "&summary=" + this.selectedtext.split(' ').join('%20') + "&source=SourceHere";
        this.emaillink = "mailto:?subject=" + ("Email subject line here.").split(' ').join('%20') + "&body=" + this.selectedtext.split(' ').join('%20') + (". Some additional text here if you want, http%3A%2F%2Fwww.WebsiteLinkHere.com.").split(' ').join('%20');

    }

    getStyle() {
        if(this.showStyle) {
            return "block";
        } else {
            return "none";
        }
    }

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

}
```

I hope this can help anyone else looking to do something similar!